# Retrieving username and gender from Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

This is how I retrieve the information stored in shared preference and later am comparing whether username and password exists. If user is logged in I am able to show another activity.

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);

```
    String username = settings.getString("username", "");


    String password = settings.getString("password", "");
```

But now I am trying to retrieve  the username and gender of the user and display in my activity.

I am trying to solve this, but not yet found the convincing result.

Can any one help me to get out of my requirement?

Note: I am also seeing the documents of Facebook developer's page

---

This is the code I am using to retrieve the user data and display in another activity. What problem am facing is the layout is loaded before the response from the facebook is paresed. I suspect it is because of the use of mAsyncRunner as it takes the control on its own. What I am trying to find out is hwo to parse it before the layout is loaded.

```
public class FaceBookRetrieval extends Activity{


this.facebookConnector = new FacebookConnect(APP_ID, this,
                getApplicationContext(), PERMS);

}

public class FacebookConnect {

    public FacebookConnect fb = null;
    private Facebook facebook = null;
    private Context context;
    private String[] permissions;
    public static final String TAG = "FACEBOOK";
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    public  String fbName, fbGender;
    private Activity activity;
    public String check = "false";
    private SessionListener mSessionListener = new SessionListener();;

    public FacebookConnect(String appId, Activity activity, Context context,
            String[] permissions) {
        this.facebook = new Facebook(appId);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        SessionStore.restore(facebook, context);
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
        SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(mSessionListener);

        this.context = context;
        this.permissions = permissions;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void login() {
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,
                    new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    }

    public void getID() {

            login();


        return;
    }

    public boolean isSession() {
        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
        Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
        Log.d(TAG, access_token);
        facebook.setAccessToken(null);
        facebook.setAccessExpires(-1);

        if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
//          facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
//          facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);



        }

        return facebook.isSessionValid();
    }



    // request the facebook to provide the response and then parse the response to 
    // obtain username and gender
    private class IDRequestListener implements RequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            try {

                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                fbGender = json.getString("gender");
                fbName = json.getString("name");
                check = "true";

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FacebookConnect.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            return ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {

        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
    }



    private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            String token = facebook.getAccessToken();
            long token_expires = facebook.getAccessExpires();
            Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
            Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);
            sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            sharedPrefs.edit().putLong("access_expires", token_expires).clear()
                    .commit();
            sharedPrefs.edit().putString("access_token", token).clear().commit();
            mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
            Toast.makeText(context, "You are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "OnCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    private class SessionListener implements AuthListener, LogoutListener {

        public void onAuthSucceed() {
            SessionStore.save(facebook, context);
        }

        public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        }

        public void onLogoutBegin() {
        }

        public void onLogoutFinish() {
            SessionStore.clear(context);
        }
    }

    public Facebook getFacebook() {
        return this.facebook;
    }


}
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: 1) You did post the same question not even 24h ago. If you found out new relevant information or have more example code, please edit your old question, don't create a duplicate. 2) You didn't post any new information or code. You will only get answers here if you come up with a solution that shows research effort. Even if it does not work right at the start. We will help you with problems, but we won't do your job for you, which is writing code by yourself.

Comment: I just deleted the older question since this one has more information, but @alextsc is right.  Please edit your questions in the future instead of posting duplicates.

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to do there's no way to help you; what APIs are you using, what error messages [if any] are you getting? What permissions have you obtained from the Facebook user whose details you want to use?

Comment: Can you tell me why I am getting invocation target exception for this line?       
                mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
This line is inside when I am checking whether the session is valid.

Comment: @thejaswi i need to get the user's friends birthdate with name. is it possible to get and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally am able to solve my problem myself.

```
private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "publish_stream" };
----->


this.facebookConnector = new FacebookConnect(APP_ID, this, getApplicationContext(), PERMS);

---->

JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);


fbGender = json.getString("gender");


fbName = json.getString("name");
```

This is a piece of my code how i extracted the data

Comment: Finally I got the answer for all of my questions. Thanks to my self.